# Display success message after form submission in mysqli prepare

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to display success message after record is inserted successfully. This code work perfectly but doesn't shows any message.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$massage=$_POST['massage'];
$organization=$_POST['organization'];

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO massage_board(name,email,organization,massage)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $name, $email, $organization, $massage);

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "<div id=\"success\"><h2>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</h2></div>";

header('Location:contact.html');
}else{
echo "Please retry";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your message  display but It redirect to another page so you do not see it try following code without redirect on page.

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "<div id=\"success\"><h2>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</h2></div>";

header('Location:contact.html');   <--- Remove this line
}
```

Comment: Have you got solution to removing `header('Location:contact.html');`

Comment: When you remove header then what you get?

Comment: You mean record inserted successfully but do not display anything?

Comment: Have you javascript or jquery for hide and show div?

Comment: What you mean by remove everything? what are you remove?

Comment: Removed css stylesheets and jquery links. now i am figuring out this where the problem occures

Answer (score 0):

It went to `contact.html` immediately after shown the message, so you couldn't see the message :)
You should do this by Javascript

```
echo "<div id=\"success\"><h2>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</h2></div>";
echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://www.example.com/contact.html';\",1500);</script>";
```

**UPDATE:**
Try this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO massage_board(name,email,organization,massage)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $organization, $massage);

if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "<div id=\"success\"><h2>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</h2></div>";

echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://www.example.com/contact.html';\",1500);</script>";
}else{
echo "Please retry";    
}
```

Comment: but it doesn't show the massage i did removed header redirection.

Comment: I've tested and its working fine. Just replace `header('Location:contact.html');` with `echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://www.example.com/contact.html';\",1500);</script>";`

Comment: Wait... what did you mean `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if($stmt->execute()){}`?
Try this:
`$stmt = mysqli_prepare(.....);
$stmt->bind_param(....)
if($stmt->execute()){}`

Comment: Thank you for you help but the header works perfect so why i would user javascript instead. My problem is that the form doesn't show success massage. It redirects to any address i wish.

Comment: I know, but if you use header, it will redirect to other page immediately, so you can't see the success message, your app must pause a while after show success message then redirect. So you need to use Javascript with `setTimeout` function to make sure your success message will display in a while before redirection